# From date dimension table to hierarchy

Tags: sql, hierarchy, data-warehouse, postgresql-10

This is my table:

```
idDate  timeformat  timeformatdate idYear YearName idSemester semestername idquarter quartername idmonth month idweek week idday day  

20160101    2016-01-01  01-Jan-16   2016    2016    1   S1  1   Q1  201601  Jan         53  W53         1   Friday   , 1                                      
20160102    2016-01-02  02-Jan-16   2016    2016    1   S1  1   Q1  201601  Jan         53  W53         2   Saturday , 2                                      
20160103    2016-01-03  03-Jan-16   2016    2016    1   S1  1   Q1  201601  Jan         53  W53         3   Sunday   , 3                                      
20160104    2016-01-04  04-Jan-16   2016    2016    1   S1  1   Q1  201601  Jan         1   W1          4   Monday   , 4                                      
20160105    2016-01-05  05-Jan-16   2016    2016    1   S1  1   Q1  201601  Jan         1   W1          5   Tuesday  , 5                                      
20160106    2016-01-06  06-Jan-16   2016    2016    1   S1  1   Q1  201601  Jan         1   W1          6   Wednesday, 6                                      
20160107    2016-01-07  07-Jan-16   2016    2016    1   S1  1   Q1  201601  Jan         1   W1          7   Thursday , 7                                      
20160108    2016-01-08  08-Jan-16   2016    2016    1   S1  1   Q1  201601  Jan         1   W1          8   Friday   , 8                                      
20160109    2016-01-09  09-Jan-16   2016    2016    1   S1  1   Q1  201601  Jan         1   W1          9   Saturday , 9                                      
20160110    2016-01-10  10-Jan-16   2016    2016    1   S1  1   Q1  201601  Jan         1   W1          10  Sunday   , 10                                     
20160111    2016-01-11  11-Jan-16   2016    2016    1   S1  1   Q1  201601  Jan         2   W2          11  Monday   , 11                                     
20160112    2016-01-12  12-Jan-16   2016    2016    1   S1  1   Q1  201601  Jan         2   W2          12  Tuesday  , 12                                     
20160113    2016-01-13  13-Jan-16   2016    2016    1   S1  1   Q1  201601  Jan         2   W2          13  Wednesday, 13                                     
20160114    2016-01-14  14-Jan-16   2016    2016    1   S1  1   Q1  201601  Jan         2   W2          14  Thursday , 14                                     
20160115    2016-01-15  15-Jan-16   2016    2016    1   S1  1   Q1  201601  Jan         2   W2          15  Friday   , 15                                     
20160116    2016-01-16  16-Jan-16   2016    2016    1   S1  1   Q1  201601  Jan         2   W2          16  Saturday , 16                                     
20160117    2016-01-17  17-Jan-16   2016    2016    1   S1  1   Q1  201601  Jan         2   W2          17  Sunday   , 17                                     
20160118    2016-01-18  18-Jan-16   2016    2016    1   S1  1   Q1  201601  Jan         3   W3          18  Monday   , 18                                     
20160119    2016-01-19  19-Jan-16   2016    2016    1   S1  1   Q1  201601  Jan         3   W3          19  Tuesday  , 19                                     
20160120    2016-01-20  20-Jan-16   2016    2016    1   S1  1   Q1  201601  Jan         3   W3          20  Wednesday, 20                                     
20160121    2016-01-21  21-Jan-16   2016    2016    1   S1  1   Q1  201601  Jan         3   W3          21  Thursday , 21                                     
20160122    2016-01-22  22-Jan-16   2016    2016    1   S1  1   Q1  201601  Jan         3   W3          22  Friday   , 22                                     
20160123    2016-01-23  23-Jan-16   2016    2016    1   S1  1   Q1  201601  Jan         3   W3          23  Saturday , 23                                     
20160124    2016-01-24  24-Jan-16   2016    2016    1   S1  1   Q1  201601  Jan         3   W3          24  Sunday   , 24                                     
20160125    2016-01-25  25-Jan-16   2016    2016    1   S1  1   Q1  201601  Jan         4   W4          25  Monday   , 25                                     
20160126    2016-01-26  26-Jan-16   2016    2016    1   S1  1   Q1  201601  Jan         4   W4          26  Tuesday  , 26                                     
20160127    2016-01-27  27-Jan-16   2016    2016    1   S1  1   Q1  201601  Jan         4   W4          27  Wednesday, 27                                     
20160128    2016-01-28  28-Jan-16   2016    2016    1   S1  1   Q1  201601  Jan         4   W4          28  Thursday , 28                                     
20160129    2016-01-29  29-Jan-16   2016    2016    1   S1  1   Q1  201601  Jan         4   W4          29  Friday   , 29                                     
20160130    2016-01-30  30-Jan-16   2016    2016    1   S1  1   Q1  201601  Jan         4   W4          30  Saturday , 30                                     
20160131    2016-01-31  31-Jan-16   2016    2016    1   S1  1   Q1  201601  Jan         4   W4          31  Sunday   , 31
```

I'm trying to create a time_hierarchy via a SQL statement.
What i want to achieve is for example:

```
Time
[2016] as Year
[Q1, 2016] as Quarter
[Jan, 2016] as Month
[Jan, 1, 2016] as Day
Etc...
```

I've really no idea how to achieve this or if my table do not support this kind of hierarchy.

Could you help me?

Thanks

Comment: su by hierarchy you mean indentation?..

Comment: Nope indentation is not required, what i want is to have a time hierarchy based on my table

Comment: @xCloudx8 What do you mean a time hierarchy?  Your example just makes it look like indentation, which you say it's not?  Could you clarify your example output more?  *(Showing column names, etc.  And possibly a description of how that expected output would then subsequently get used?)*

Comment: @MatBailie Yeah you're right. Well, i want in a single columnthe output i've wrote on my question. Just image a drop down button with that info.

Comment: Then you'll want more than one column, surely?  You'll want a column for the level of aggregation *(year, quarter, month, day)*, a column for the label *(the column in your example?)* and probably two columns for "first date" and "last date" so that you can join on to the results?  Which brings up a pertinent point that you didn't answer : `And possibly a description of how that expected output would then subsequently get used?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN quarterName IS NULL THEN 'Year'
       WHEN month       IS NULL THEN 'Quarter'
       WHEN idDay       IS NULL THEN 'Month'
                                ELSE 'Day'
  END
    AS aggregateLevel,
  CASE WHEN quarterName IS NULL THEN YearName
       WHEN month       IS NULL THEN QuarterName || ', ' || YearName
       WHEN idDay       IS NULL THEN Month || ', ' || YearName
                                ELSE Month || ', ' || CAST(idDay AS VARCHAR(2)) || YearName
  END
    AS periodTitle,
  MIN(idDate)   AS periodFirstDate,
  MAX(idDate)   AS periodFinalDate
FROM
  yourTable
GROUP BY
  GROUPING SETS (
    (YearName),
    (YearName, quarterName),
    (YearName, quarterName, month),
    (YearName, quarterName, month, idDay)
  )
ORDER BY
  MIN(idDate),
  MAX(idDate) DESC
```

Comment: this is awesome!